# Spark RDD String Aggregate

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i'm a level -3 Newbie in Scala/Spark;i have and `RDD[String,String]` containing n word per line as:

```
id1, cat fish
id1, eat red
id2, blue Dog
```

And i like to get a `RDD[String,String]` like:

```
id1, cat fish eat red
id2, blue Dog
```

So far i've tried a `groupByKey`

`val rdd2 = rdd1.groupByKey()`

Thank You in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
rdd1.reduceByKey((s1, s2) => s1 + " " + s2)
```

Comment: Thanks , i solved like this : rdd1.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)) but your solution is much better.